# Create/Edit/Check cPanel Email Accounts from Wordpress

Tags: plugin-recommendation, email

I need a plugin (or other) recommendation to allow users to create email accounts, as well as change their passwords and check their email using WordPress.

I have a multi-author baseball website and I would like to allow authors to create their own email addresses at my domain name, if they like.

That being said, I do not want to create the email addresses myself. I do not want/need to know the authors' passwords to the accounts and want them to know I respect their privacy.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you have new authors regularly or do you only have new authors every now and then?

Comment: As a side note, your ChiefsCommand link doesn't work on your website

Comment: I'm not sure how your question is relevant. As I said, if an author wants to create an email address, I want them to be able to do it without giving me a password to create it for them and if they want to change their password, I want them to be able to do it themselves.

Comment: WordPress simply isn't a webmail interface, or anything close to that. The mail functions are basically wrappers for basic PHP mail stuff. If you couldn't find any plugin for this yourself, than I'm sorry to say, but WPSE isn't an extended search engine and the question is considered _off topic_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[I've successfully used this to enable users to create an email account and/or ftp account on cpanel from within a WordPress site.](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/cpanel-operations/)
 Good luck, and let me know how it went.

There seems to be a small bug in the latest plugin version. You can easily fix it, I've described the steps below:

1. Open your code editor
2. Open up search and replace
3. Select the plugin folder to search
4. Search the source code for `/cpanel_ops/`
5. Replace it with `/cpanel-operations/`
6. Save your changes on these files

It should say that four instances have been replaced within 3 files:

1. /cpanel_ops.php
2. /email_form.php
3. /ftp_form.php

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I have been searching for something like this for months. The developer really needs to put more effort in the description/name of the plugin. I will give it a try today.

Comment: No problem, just hope it will help you.

Comment: I'm getting a 404 page not found error when clicking on either "Create FTP account" or "Create email account". Using WordPress 3.3.2. Did you experience any errors?

Comment: It's working on an older WP version. Will try it on 3.3.2 later. Did you correctly set the permissions?

Comment: Yes, everything is set up with my cPanel credentials. Did you try it on a 3.3.2 installation of WordPress?

Comment: @TravisPflanz I've created a test account and installed this on version 3.3.2 and now it's working. I've updated my answer.

Comment: @TravisPflanz did you get this working?